# Favicon not showing up in Firefox or Chrome

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, favicon

I've uploaded a favicon.ico to my client's root (htdocs) directory on the server and added
the following before the `</head>` tag:

```
<link type="image/x-icon" rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico"/>
<link type="image/x-icon" rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico"/>
```

It loads fine in every browser EXCEPT for Firefox and Chrome. In those two, although the 
icon loads in the tab, it does not load in the web address bar. In Firefox I see a globe
icon and in Chrome I see a document icon.

Comment: I've also tried using the full URL to the .ico file - still no joy.

Comment: Try to use png icons, some browsers cannot read .ico, use `<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://example.com/icon.png">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't this normal in Chrome and FF? I don't see the favicon in the address bar on any side in chrome. There the are displayed in the tab. The doc icon is use to show detailed information about the page.
If you find a page showing a favicon in the address bar you can look at the page source to find out how they did it.

Comment: You're right - I checked sites like CNN and Google, and their favicons weren't showing either.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there are no favicons shown any more in Firefox since some sites used a "lock" symbol as favicon such mocking a secure connection (the secure connection logo would appear next to the favicon on the left of the URL). The favicons will still be shown in tabs and bookmarks though.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine (unless there's no such file for the favicon). You just need to clear your browser's cache or reload the page with purged cache (Ctrl+F5). However, you should know that it takes a while for FF/Chrome to recognize new favicons, so instead you can test them in other computers/browsers from which you haven't visited your site yet.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a real programmer and I had a similar problem and here is the simple thing that finally worked for me...

I admin several simple websites but Firefox refused to load the favicon of one in particular site. I looked online, tried everything I was able to understand. Nothing worked. The code was exactly the same (copied in fact) from the other websites whose icons worked well.

Eventually it dawned on me that maybe Firefox did not like the path I used to get there. This site was a forwarded URL being hosted on my own domain. (i.e. personal domain is myplace.ca and the favicon that would not load was part of registered URL something.com which was actually located at myplace.ca/PutItHere/) If I used the registered URL (something.com) no favicon. If I use the real path in the browser, suddenly favicon! All I had to do was bookmark the absolute path rather than the registered domain!

Answer (score 0):

```
...href="favicon.ico"/>"
```

Please note the `"favicon.ico"` in above line and avoid your prepended forward slash if it is in the root folder.
It works fine for Firefox 24.0