# Change image icon in addressbar of browser

Tags: image, icons, browser

I searched through many sites, but I failed to get an answer.

Question :
 I want to change icon as per given in below image in my browser.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a favicon?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547150/how-to-create-a-favicon)

Comment: my question is not regarding favicon how can you say its a duplicate please read question carefully first@cody Gray.

Comment: That thing you've circled is called a favicon.

Comment: so why favicon display in tab not where i have circled.

Comment: Firefox and Chrome don't display favicons there. You'll need to write another browser, or submit a feature request to the dev teams.  See also: [Favicon not showing up in Firefox or Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12820492)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently chrome and Mozilla does not support this feature if you want check you can check it in either ie or safari, it will show where you want.

Comment: yuppp i have check it.

Comment: I don't believe any browser would or should support changing the icon in the address bar since it provides information about the website, including security-related information.  I would be extremely suspicious of any website that tried changing that icon.

Answer (score 2):

you should add this tag to head

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<YOUR ICON PATH>">
```

this is a tool to help you to create icon using converter
http://www.favicongenerator.com/

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. i have try this but it display the icon in tab ( with title ). i want image as per above image not in tab(favicon icon).

Comment: <your icon path>  put ur icon path here

Comment: i have try this but it will display in tab not where i have circled

Comment: It's depand on browser where is display.

Answer (score 1):

Those are called "favicons", and you can set one for your website using a special tag in the `HEAD` of your HTML. You can find many tutorials on this by Googling (now that you know what they're called).

[Wikipedia suggests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#How_to_use) a tag something like this:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://example.com/myicon.ico" />
```

As an alternative, your website can provide an image named `favicon.ico` in the root folder.

Answer (score 1):

That icon names "favicon". To create Something like that go to [THIS LINK](http://www.favicon.cc/), Upload an image and get the favicon.ico file, then put it next to your template page on your host.

To get more information go [HERE](http://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon).